# How can 'turnover' be interpreted figuratively?

Tags: word-meaning, figurative-language

> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/207719?rskey=NWAfgs&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) A. 1. a. The action of turning over, in various senses: see quots.;
> (Polit. slang) a transference of votes from one party to another.

I understand the morphemes 'turn' and over' and the literal meaning of 'turnover', per above. Instead, how does **turnover** figuratively mean the following?   A business doesn't turn over the money received.    'Turning over people' sounds barbarous, but this noun is frequently used with neutral connotation.

> [[ODO:]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turnover) 1. The amount of money taken by a business in a particular period:
>
> 2. The rate at which employees leave a workforce and are replaced
>
> [I ask NOT about definition 3 for 'A small pie ...', which is literal enough for me to  understand.]

Footnote: I don't think that this question concerns etymology, but if I've erred, please advise.

Comment: Business is barbarous.  Just ask Human Resources.  You need to meditate on *turn* in relation to cycles (in a particular recurrent time-period [daily, weekly, monthly, yearly], with hiring and firing or quitting, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "revolving door" is used to express situations where people are constantly entering and leaving a place, even if there is no physical revolving door, and this, to me, is what *turnover* is figuratively expressing.